# external css loaded but not aplied to html - php codeigniter ssl - how to change css mimetype = text/html to text/css

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, ssl

I'm trying to make an Facebook app, but I have a problem with my CSS. Everything is working well on my localhost, but on my server external CSS are loaded up but not applied to HTML. The site is https://app.pomyslnazdrowie.pl, and its shown below:

[image]

If I save webpage from server on my computer as static files everything works perfect.

Could this be something wrong with CodeIgniter or SSL or both? Any ideas?

Comment: Your browser’s error console should enlighten you …

Comment: Looks like all of your CSS resources are delivered by the server with `Content-Type: text/html` – which is of course wrong, and will make modern browsers refuse to interpret them as CSS; it should be `text/css` instead. So go see to it that you get your server configured to send that for CSS resources.

Comment: Probably mixed content if its working locally but not remotely. That is, the web page is being fetched via SSL, but the CSS or Javascript is being fetched using plain HTTP. See the W3C's [Mixed Content](http://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/mixedcontent). Given the picture of the browser and the half-shield, its likely mixed content.

Comment: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Mozilla_Css_Mime_Type

Comment: i tried to overwrite those setting in htacces by defaultType, force type, addtype. httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype nothing.

i also tried on this domain wordpress and there is no similiar problem so i think that this should be codeigniter fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the hosting settings and my .htaccess. I needed to force php 5.4 but I've done it wrong. My .htaccess was:

```
Use php54
```

And should be:

```
:Location /*.php
Use php54
:Location
```

I don't know if this answer will help anyone but this was home.pl hosting.

Thanks.